# Advice for JavaScript Design pattern

Tags: javascript, architecture

I have a JavaScript variable that is used by 10 different functions on the same page. These functions set and get value from this variable and perform certain actions. I would like to know if I can follow some architecture for sharing common resource between functions.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what your code looks like?

Comment: give an example and explain what issues you are having

Comment: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: Question is based on javascript design pattern if present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you. You can insert the variable as an argument on every function or set it as a global variable. If you're working with OOP then you'd better set that variable as a property of the prototype.